# Laravel Time Range

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent, laravel-5.8

I am using Laravel 5.8 and I have two columns with data type timestamp, start_time and end_time. Before saving a new record I want to check if it already exists.

For example if I have already in my database **Start Time= 09:00:00, End Time: 17:00:00** I should not set start time = *13:00:00 and end_time=16:00:00*  because it is already in the existing interval, and I should not register also *16:00:00->20:00:00* because the 16:00:00 is in the interval.

So far I have this, which doesn't work:

```php
DB::table('student_classes')
    ->where('id', '!=', $id)
    ->whereNotBetween('start_date', [$data['start_date'], $data['end_date']]);
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: DB::table('student_classes')->where('id', '!=', $id)->whereNotBetween('start_date' , [$data['start_date'],$data['end_date']]  ), that did not work

Comment: Would you allow insert for `08:00:00` to `09:00:00`? and why are you doing `id != $id`?

Comment: What if someone saves the record *while* you're checking? Don't check. Just build the logic into the 'save'.

Comment: @JitendraYadav id!=id means if editing it may gives you your current model, so I am excluding my current record

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@MahdiMiad how are you saving time in the database - is it timestamp or string? I hope you are using the timestamp.

Do query before you are saving it.

```
$rows = DB::table('student_classes')->whereNotBetween('start_date', [$data['start_date'],$data['end_date']])->get();
if (count($rows)>0) {
    // throw error
} else {
    // save the results
}
```

Comment: Yes I am saving as timestamp, Thanks for your answer